# Is physics driven animation on a human scale possible in blender

Tags: animation, physics

By physics driven I mean sorta like [toribash](http://www.toribash.com/), or [sumotori dreams](http://www.gravitysensation.com/sumotori/) if you have heard of those. Basically I want a ragdoll that I can apply forces to in certain spots to mimic human movement.

For reference I don't know a whole lot about blender but I am pretty good with python and I know blender has pretty good python support.

If it is not possible in blender is it possible in any other 3d tools.